# Check whether a box-shadow is already applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Javascript is there a way to check if an element already has a box-shadow applied?

I am doing this because I am adding a inner(inset) box-shadow when there may already be an outer shadow. If there's already a shadow I need to place a comma before the new styling text.

```
var shadowStyle = "5px 5px #000000";

if (ele.hasBoxShadow())
{
   ele.style.boxShadow += ", "+shadowStyle;
   ele.style.WebkitBoxShadow += ", "+shadowStyle;
   ele.style.MozBoxShadow += ", "+shadowStyle;
   ele.style.OBoxShadow += ", "+shadowStyle;
   ele.style.MsBoxShadow += ", "+shadowStyle;
}
else ele.style.boxShadow = shadowStyle;
     ...
```

Comment: Can't you just check if any of those are set?  `if (ele.style.boxShadow || ele.style.Web...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it with `ele.hasBoxShadow()`.

```
Element.prototype.hasBoxShadow = function() {
    return window
            .getComputedStyle(this)
            .getPropertyCSSValue('box-shadow')
            .cssText != 'none';
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26hpg/).

It also [works](http://jsfiddle.net/sb6et/) if the property is set with a vendor prefix (at least it does in Firefox 8)

I wouldn't recommend augmenting the `Element`'s `prototype`, however. Make a *utility* object and add this as a method.